# Nested SQL Insert in Postgre Function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, supabase-database

I have this function that is triggered, when a new user signs up in my app (supabase backen):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.handle_new_user()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$
begin
  insert into public.user_profile (id, email, full_name)
  values (new.id, new.email, new.raw_user_meta_data->>'full_name');
  return new;
end;
$function$
;
```

Now I want to first insert a row to another table and put the resulting `id` of this row inside a new column in my `user_profile`.

Something like this:

```
  id = insert into other_table (created_by, somecolumn)
  values (new.id, 100000);
  
  insert into public.user_profile (id, email, full_name, foreign_column)
  values (new.id, new.email, new.raw_user_meta_data->>'full_name', id);
  return new;
```

What is the correct syntax in postgreSQL to do this `insertAndSelect`? So that I can use it to insert the foreign_key into my `user_profile` afterwards?

**EDIT: my table definitions**

```
create table
  public.user_profile (
    id uuid not null,
    full_name text null,
    email text not null,
    spending_cap integer null,
    constraint profiles_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint user_profile_id_fkey foreign key (id) references auth.users (id),
    constraint user_profile_spending_cap_fkey foreign key (spending_cap) references spending_cap (id)
  ) tablespace pg_default;
  
  
create table
  public.spending_cap (
    id integer generated by default as identity,
    created_by uuid null,
    cap bigint null,
    constraint lobby_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint spending_cap_created_by_fkey foreign key (created_by) references user_profile (id)
  ) tablespace pg_default;
```

I took the trigger from this [guide](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/managing-user-data#advanced-techniques)

```
-- trigger the function every time a user is created
create trigger on_auth_user_created
  after insert on auth.users
  for each row execute procedure public.handle_new_user();
```

The `auth.user` table is created by supabase and is big:

```
create table
  auth.users (
    instance_id uuid null,
    id uuid not null,
    aud character varying(255) null,
    role character varying(255) null,
    email character varying(255) null,
    encrypted_password character varying(255) null,
    email_confirmed_at timestamp with time zone null,
    invited_at timestamp with time zone null,
    confirmation_token character varying(255) null,
    confirmation_sent_at timestamp with time zone null,
    recovery_token character varying(255) null,
    recovery_sent_at timestamp with time zone null,
    email_change_token_new character varying(255) null,
    email_change character varying(255) null,
    email_change_sent_at timestamp with time zone null,
    last_sign_in_at timestamp with time zone null,
    raw_app_meta_data jsonb null,
    raw_user_meta_data jsonb null,
    is_super_admin boolean null,
    created_at timestamp with time zone null,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone null,
    phone text null default null::character varying,
    phone_confirmed_at timestamp with time zone null,
    phone_change text null default ''::character varying,
    phone_change_token character varying(255) null default ''::character varying,
    phone_change_sent_at timestamp with time zone null,
    confirmed_at timestamp with time zone null,
    email_change_token_current character varying(255) null default ''::character varying,
    email_change_confirm_status smallint null default 0,
    banned_until timestamp with time zone null,
    reauthentication_token character varying(255) null default ''::character varying,
    reauthentication_sent_at timestamp with time zone null,
    is_sso_user boolean not null default false,
    deleted_at timestamp with time zone null,
    constraint users_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint users_phone_key unique (phone),
    constraint users_email_change_confirm_status_check check (
      (
        (email_change_confirm_status >= 0)
        and (email_change_confirm_status <= 2)
      )
    )
  ) tablespace pg_default;

create unique index confirmation_token_idx on auth.users using btree (confirmation_token)
where
  ((confirmation_token)::text !~ '^[0-9 ]*$'::text) tablespace pg_default;

create unique index email_change_token_current_idx on auth.users using btree (email_change_token_current)
where
  (
    (email_change_token_current)::text !~ '^[0-9 ]*$'::text
  ) tablespace pg_default;

create unique index email_change_token_new_idx on auth.users using btree (email_change_token_new)
where
  (
    (email_change_token_new)::text !~ '^[0-9 ]*$'::text
  ) tablespace pg_default;

create unique index reauthentication_token_idx on auth.users using btree (reauthentication_token)
where
  (
    (reauthentication_token)::text !~ '^[0-9 ]*$'::text
  ) tablespace pg_default;

create unique index recovery_token_idx on auth.users using btree (recovery_token)
where
  ((recovery_token)::text !~ '^[0-9 ]*$'::text) tablespace pg_default;

create unique index users_email_partial_key on auth.users using btree (email)
where
  (is_sso_user = false) tablespace pg_default;

create index if not exists users_instance_id_email_idx on auth.users using btree (instance_id, lower((email)::text)) tablespace pg_default;

create index if not exists users_instance_id_idx on auth.users using btree (instance_id) tablespace pg_default;

create trigger on_auth_user_created
after insert on auth.users for each row
execute function handle_new_user ();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RETURNING to set the value for a variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.handle_new_user()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    SECURITY DEFINER
AS
$function$
DECLARE
    _id_other_table INT;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO other_table (created_by, somecolumn)
    VALUES (new.id, 100000)
    RETURNING id
        INTO _id_other_table;

    INSERT INTO public.user_profile (id, email, full_name, foreign_column)
    VALUES (new.id, new.email, new.raw_user_meta_data ->> 'full_name', _id_other_table);

    RETURN new;
END;
$function$;
```

Comment: Thanks! I get `failed to send batch: ERROR: insert or update on table "other_table" violates foreign key constraint "other_table_created_by_fkey" (SQLSTATE 23503)`. Could this be because `new.id` is not yet a public user? If yes, maybe I need to first insert a `user_profile`, then insert into `other_table` and then update `user_profile` again.

Comment: Please post the table definitions (DDL) for **all** tables involved, include constraints. Post as an update to your question not as a comment.

Comment: @progNewbie Are you sure you want a trigger function for this?

Comment: @FrankHeikens I don't know how to do it otherwise. This function is triggered when a new account is added in my supabase auth. And I want to create these two entries and link them for each new user.

Comment: @progNewbie The error message tells you that something went wrong with the insert on "other_table", a foreign key violation. We have no idea about the structure of this table, you didn't share any DDL. And I'm still having doubts about this trigger function, you didn't share the DDL for the trigger itself nor the table that is used to fire the trigger and the trigger function. My gut feeling tells me there is something wrong in the entire setup.

Comment: I edited my post and included the DDL of my tables. I don't know how to get the DDL of the trigger or the fireing table because this happens from somewhere within supabase-db. I am really new to trigger functions in general. Thank you.

Comment: @progNewbie Where is the table with the column raw_user_meta_data? And I don't see any trigger for this unknown table as well. This question is getting way bigger than just a question about some syntax. Cut the question up into smaller pieces

Comment: @FrankHeikens I don't know. I just followed this [guide](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/managing-user-data#advanced-techniques). I added the trigger creation to my question.